# Product detailed page get 404 in one store view

Tags: magento2, product

I have 2 store views. One is in Chinese and another one is in English. After I import the product information programmatically. Only the store view in the Chinese could display the product detailed page. The store view in English gets 404. I found in url_rewrite table only Chinese store view have rewrite record like the following:
[image]

store_id = 1 is the Chinese store view. but there is no record for the English store view whose store_id = 2.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, SKUs must be set for each store view when you import individual product content for each store view. Thus, the correct Magento 2 approach looks as follows:

```
sku,store_view_code,name
1111,,"Default name"
1111,et,"Translated name"
1111,ru,"Another translation"
```

For more details you can check this [blog](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-import-individual-product-data-for-each-store-view-in-magento-2.html)

You can also check out a [module](https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html) for an improved way of importing products to your store view.